# How do I resolve this int overflow?

Tags: c, cs50

```
int frequency(string note)
{
    int i;
    float f;
    int n=0;
    float octave= note[strlen(note)-1];
    if(strlen(note)==3)
    {
        if(note[1]=='#')
        {
            n+=1;
        }
        else if(note[1]=='b')
        {
            n-=1;
        }
    }
    if(note[0]=='B')
    {
        n+=2;
    }
    else if(note[0]=='C')
    {
        n-=9;
    }
    else if(note[0]=='D')
    {
        n-=7;
    }
    else if(note[0]=='E')
    {
        n-=5;
    }
    else if(note[0]=='F')
    {
        n-=4;
    }
    else if(note[0]=='G')
    {
            n-=2;
        }
        n+=(octave-4.0)*12.0;
        float p= n/12.0;
        f=(int)(round(pow(2.0,p)*440.0));
        return f;
    }
```

So basically whenever I run this code I get an error stating "runtime error: value 7.3641e+16 is outside the range of representable values of type 'int'"

Then the value returned is just-2147483648. I've looked it up online and haven't found an answer that helps me with my code. Also this was made in the cs50 IDE so there are a bunch of commands and things that are imported. My program compiles properly and it can run so how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frequencies of notes of the chromatic scale are not integers in the first place.

If you are passed a two character string like Cb, you get a stupidly huge octive with a frequency way too high.

Comment: yea i just figured it out i changed the last 4-5 lines to `f= round(440.0* (pow(2.0,n/12.0)))` and whenever i change n I add .0 by the digit that changes it.